# Inputing multiple strings into a 2D array with pointers

Tags: c

I'm passing on the address of the first row of my array to the first function. When you go through 1 loop the second time around it skips over the first function for some reason, even though I've changed the row address. I get a warning that says passing of argument 1 of 'getHousing' from incompatible pointer type but its a pointer to an address to the first row. The code isn't finished yet, also, I'm still pretty new to c thanks!

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define DISCOUNT 10
#define UNITCOST 100
#define NAMESIZE 30
#define NAMES 5
#define RESPONSE 4
#define MAXUNITS 10
#define YESNO 15


void getName(char* name);
void getHousing(char* housing);
void getUnits(int* units);
int amountDue(char* housing, int unit);

int main()
{
    char names[NAMES][NAMESIZE];

    char house[YESNO];

    int  units[MAXUNITS];

    int  amountdue[NAMES];


    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        getName(names[i]);
        getHousing(house);
        getUnits(units);
        puts("");
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        amountDue(house,units[i]);
    }
}


void getName(char* name)
{
    printf("Enter student name: ");
    fgets(name,NAMESIZE,stdin);
    name[ strspn( name, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
}


void getHousing(char* housing)
{
    printf("Enter yes if student lives on campus, no otherwise: ");
    fgets(housing,RESPONSE,stdin);
}


void getUnits(int* units)
{
    printf("Enter current unit count: ");
    scanf("%d", units);
}


int amountDue(char* housing, int unit)
{

}
```

Comment: The code, as posted, won't compile. When you do get it to compile, turn up the compiler warnings. You are passing the wrong type to the `getName()` function.

Comment: what should I be passing to it then, a pointer? because i need to go through the function 5 more times the pointer only points to the first row and so i need give it the address of each row for each name I'm trying to get

Comment: Why are you subtracting here? `getName(&names[I] - i);`

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding:  1) separate code blocks: `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default`  via a single blank line.  2) separate functions via 2 or 3 blank lines ( be consistent )  3) insert an appropriate space: inside parens, inside braces, inside brackets, after commas, after semicolons, around C operators.

Comment: Note:  an array name, with no qualifiers degrades to the address of the first byte of the array.  When accessing `char names[NAMES][NAMESIZE];`  then `names[x]` is an array so do not use `&`.  Similar considerations exist for other array accesses.

Comment: regarding: `getName( names[i] - i );`  the parameter: `names[i]` accesses one of the names 'rows'   so what is the `-i` expected to do?

Comment: regarding: `int  amountdue[5];`  this declares an array of 5 integers.  However, it is using the 'magic' number 5  Why not use `int  amountdue[ NAMES ];`?   Remember that macros are treated by the compiler as a text replacement,  so `NAMES` is replaced by 5, However, `NAMES` is much more informatives than a `5`

Comment: OT: in function: `main()` regarding: ` int i;`  it is best to limit the 'scope' of variables as much as reasonable.  Suggest removing that statement and modifying the two `for()` statements similar to: `for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )`

Comment: OT: regarding: ` fgets(name,NAMESIZE,stdin);

    if (name[strlen(name) - 1] == '\n')
    {
        name[strlen(name) - 1] = '\0';
    }`  1) always check the returned value from calls to C library functions to assure they were successful.  When not successful, call `perror( "your error message" );` to output both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the function failed to `stderr`.  2) A very good way to remove a newline is: `name[ strspn( name, "\n" ) ] = '\0';`

Comment: regarding: `for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        getName( names[i] );
        getHousing ( house );
        getUnits( units );
        puts("");
    }`  Each time through the loop, the value in `house` gets overlayed.  The result is all, but the last time through the loop, entries by the user are lost.  Probably not what you want

Comment: OT: regarding: `scanf("%d", units);`  When calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  Note: they return the number of successful input format conversions.  I.E. `if( scanf( "%d", units ) != 1 ) { fprintf( stderr, "scanf for units failed\n" ); }`  Note: when obtaining a user input fails, it is ( almost always ) useless to continue the program, so suggest calling `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: Hey thanks to everyone for the helpful comments I really appreciate it. I've taken in a lot of the inputs and it really helps with how organized my code is. But my program is still bugged during the second time in the first `for` loop in `main ()` when it goes through the `getName()` function it skips over the `fgets` and doesn't allow for user input

Comment: Also, keep in mind the program doesn't need to be bulletproof just yet my professor is just seeing if my code works as intended.

Comment: Also, shouldn't I be using a `&` because the function requires an address for the pointer to point to, in this case, its an address for the first row.

Comment: For this problem - _But my program is still bugged during the second time in the...._, share the input you are giving to your program?